# Changing Line WIdth of Line charts and Max. scale for xlCategory

Tags: vba, linechart

I created a line chart in Excel 2010. Dim co(1 To 90) As ChartObject.
How can I change its Line Width? 
I tried using:

```
co(3).Chart.Series["Quality"].BorderWidth = 1
```

Error occurred: Series is not a part of Chart objects And
Is there any workaround for implementing Max. Scale for xlCategory?

Comment: Have you tried doing it manually while recording a macro to see what the code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use..

```
co(3).Chart.Series["Quality"].SeriesCollection(1).Border.Weight = 4
```

this case the macro recorder is very helpful, do the turn you have to do and then see the code

[]´s